# Convert Key:Value paired multiple data blocks into csv file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have multiple Key:Value pair data blocks separated by delimiter "*************" in an text file.The help required here is for a shell script to convert them into csv file.

```
*************
Name : Anderson 
Age : 32 
Country : U.S
*************
Name : Pramod 
Country : U.K
*************
Country : Africa 
Sport : Football
*************
```

The Output should be the csv file with below format
OutPut :

```
Name,Age,Country,Sport
Anderson,32,U.S.A,
Pramod,,U.K,
,,Aftica,Football
```

This is kind of similar to rec2csv conversion from GNU recutils , but this I want it to get done by Shell Scripting

Comment: The Key:Value pairs are delimited by newline in same dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` for this conversion:

```
$ awk -F' : ' 'BEGIN { print "Name,Age,Country,Sport"; OFS="," }
    /^\*+$/ && NR>1 { print a["Name"], a["Age"], a["Country"], a["Sport"];
                      delete a; next}
    { a[$1]=$2} ' file.rec
```

Where `:` is used as input field seperator, `,` is set as output field seperator, the associative array `a` is used to temporarily store the values, the regular expresion `^\*+$` is used to recognize the record separating lines, a complete record is only printed after the second separating line (i.e. if number of records are greater than 1) and after each record the array is cleared.

The variables `$1` and `$2` reference the key and value in the input. The `next` statement directly advances the processing to the next line.

Not existing keys in the associative array result in empty strings - which matches the question.

Comment: Thanks Maxschlepzig for the the solution , it worked as expected.